# Did Yoda appear in Star Wars The Force awakens?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-force-awakens

Yoda is my son's favorite character. He said if Yoda is not there, he does not want to watch. Is Yoda going to be in The Force Awakens? If yes, will he be one of the main characters?

Comment: Um, you might want to remember his death in *Return of the Jedi*. So apart from the possibility of a little force-ghost cameo I don't see much hope for your son.

Comment: Sad. I was hoping for a miracle. If my son is not going to watch, I am going to watch anyway.

Comment: Just watched it, did see a few yoda like figures walking around a few times

Comment: his voice is in the part where rey has the vision along with ben kenobi

Comment: I could swear I heard Yoda's voice during Rey's force vision while a good friend says he heard Ben Kenobi.

Comment: Appear in The Force Awakens, Yoda does not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As at the end of Revenge of the Sith, Yoda is the one who teaches to Obi-Wan how to come back as a "Force ghost" (himself learning it from Qui-Gon), so it is possible that he comes back this way

/!\ Warning, Spoiler about The Force Awakens /!\

> Yoda isn't in the movie

Comment: I just ran across this
http://www.starwarsunderworld.com/2015/12/jj-abrams-confirms-cameos-from-ewan.html

Comment: I just saw the movie and (minor spoiler) I think he was shown in a flashback, but his actual face was never shown.

Answer (score 7):

Spoiler below:

> As confirmed by J.J. Abrams at a recent screening, only the voice of Ben Kenobi and Yoda are heard during Rey’s force flashback scene in *The Force Awakens*.

From an article in [Collider](http://collider.com/star-wars-7-force-awakens-cameos-jj-abrams-lawrence-kasdan-daisy-ridley/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=collidersocial) (and other places):

> *“The idea of the voices was, we wanted the audience to feel – but not necessarily be presented right in your face — this idea that familiar, Force-strong voices were connecting with her. At least as well as they could…You do hear a little bit of Yoda. You hear Luke yelling out, ‘Nooo!’ from that moment in Empire. And you hear Obi-Wan at the end say, ‘Rey, these are your first steps.’…Here’s the cool part. We asked Ewan McGregor to come in and do the line. And he was awesome and we were very grateful. He was incredibly sweet and handsome, and all that stuff. Then he rode off on his motorcycle. Literally the coolest voice over actor ever.”*
>
> And here’s what he had to say about Oz coming into the Bad Robot offices to bring back the voice of Jedi Master Yoda:
>
> *“He was incredibly generous and came in to Bad Robot, where we had a recording area, and he was doing Yoda, saying a number of lines we gave to him…This whole experience has been one outrageous moment after another. Just watching Frank Oz, you look at him and talk to him and his voice is very deep. I don’t know why I would have thought he sounded like Miss Piggy!…He was very generous to say, ‘Whatever makes the movie better, I’m happy to help out.”*

Comment: http://collider.com/star-wars-7-force-awakens-cameos-jj-abrams-lawrence-kasdan-daisy-ridley/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=collidersocial

Answer (score 5):

Yoda died in the *Return of the Jedi*, so it’s hard to see him.

Anyway in *The Empire Strikes Back* and *Return of the Jedi* we saw Obi Wan Kenobi return as a ghost, but in the [wiki page of the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens) I didn't read info about Yoda (neither the collaboration with Frank Oz, Yoda's animator).

But there is no guarantees of that.

What I can say—with huge displeasure—is that I don’t think we will see him, but this is a personal opinion.